# Using Python and Beautiful Soup to create a CSV file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it possible using Python to save a portion of a filename as a field in a CSV file? I have a series of HTML files named, say, `"000000001 8375739.html"` all the way through `"000000021 5748922937574.html"` and I'd like to be able to remove the first 10 characters (the first number is always 9 digits, and then the space) and then save the rest of the filename (minus the .html) into a field called ID in a CSV file which is then itself populated by the contents of the html file. In fact, what I'm trying to do, is to use Beautiful Soup to extract text from an HTML file, save the first line in a field called "title" save the rest of the text in a field called "body" and save the second portion of the filename in a field called "ID". The html to text portion works perfectly, however I can't seem to get the rest of it down.

This is the code that strips the HTML and writes to a (single) text file. I assume I need to make use of glob again, or do I need to use igloo?

```
import os
import glob
import codecs
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
dics = [{

path = "c:\\users\\zac\\downloads\\"

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.html")):
    markup = (infile)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(codecs.open(markup, "r", "utf-8").read())
    with open("extracted.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(soup.get_text())
```

Here's a sample of the HTML, they aren't all exactly the same but they basically follow the same format:

```
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>

          <td>
            <p><a>Some Sample Text</a> </p>
            <p><a>A slightly larger body of text. Thus far, we see that the current python script is placing this directly under the previous text.</a> </p>
            <h3><a>And a final bit of text, this has so far been placed below the previous text, making three lines of text (or more, depending on how long the middle block is).</a></h3>

          <td ></td>

          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = "000000001 8375739.html"
trash, name = fname.split(" ")
data, trash = name.split(".")

print data

--output:--
8375739
```

Why would you think that not posting a sample of your html file was the correct way to ask your question? In your opinion, are all html files identical, so BS can read the file and separate out the data that you require?

Comment: For a couple of reasons. First, because the contents of the HTML files are protected under an NDA. But, also because the BS part is working well. As of right now, I have 40 files and within my "extracted.txt" I have 40 entries, each with a line that is equal to the title, and then a block of text that is equal to the content. So, I didn't think the HTML mattered that much in this case.

Comment: Added some HTML, in case it does help.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to do.  It would have been more helpful if you had posted html that looked like this:<div>This is the text for the 'title' column of the csv file.</div><div>This the the text for the 'body' column of the csv file</div>.  How is it that you did not think of that?  "the contents of the HTML files are protected under an NDA". lol.

Comment: Well, I assumed it would be obvious enough. The HTML files are under an NDA, not sure why that's funny. You seem to have been able to figure it out easily enough, so I'm unsure why you choose to be rude in your responses. In any case, I was able to get help elsewhere.

Comment: "The HTML files are under an NDA, not sure why that's funny."  It's funny that you couldn't think to yourself, "Self, this is proprietary info, so I won't post it.  In fact, I won't even tell anyone the real data is proprietary.  I'll just post some html with data like "<div>See Dick run.</div><div>See Spot run</div>" because the important thing is how to extract the data, not the data itself.

Comment: I don't know, I think you're confusing "couldn't" with "didn't" in this case. Besides, the question was in regard to the file name, not the content of the HTML files. So, in that case, the files could be blank, or they could contain tons of HTML, either way it wouldn't matter. That's why I was, and remain, so confused by your remarks; they have nothing to do with the question.